# Delete and save Child : JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<Child>();

 ...
}
The child:

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENTID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

  ...
}
```

I want to perform following operations:

1. Delete child entity from parent (not the parent itself).
2. Add new child entity to parent (`parent.setChild(child)`).
3. Now save the child entity in to DB and update parent accordingly.

This is what I tried but it raises `ConstraintViolationexception` for parent:

```
entityManager.remove(parent.getChild())
parent.setChild(new Child())
entityManager.merge(parent);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I could not attend the chat earlier. here is what I have posted:  The sequence for removing the child probably should be like this:
* remove child from list in parent
* remove parent reference from child (you can switch the first two steps)
* either delete child from DB directly, or take advantage of orphanRemoval=true
* then, to append the new child, add the parent reference to the new child
* add the new child to the list of children in parent
* merge parent

Answer (score 3):

The 'old' child probably still references the parent, while the new child does not. Both is an issue.

In addition to removing an old child, you should set the `parent` reference of the child instance to `null`.

In addition to adding the new child to the parent, you will need to add the parent to the child in order to provide the foreign key.

Do not cascade from the many side (child) to the one side (parent). The behavior for this type of cascades is undefined and might work in an unexpected way.

EDIT: what the JPA 2.0 spec has to say:

> Note that it is the application that bears responsibility for maintaining 
>   the consistency of runtime relationships—for example, for
>   insuring that the “one” and the “many” sides of a bidirectional
>   relationship are consistent with one another when the application
>   updates the relationship at runtime.

Comment: wen I update parent. child entity should save in DB(new entry in DB).

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why you have the cascade on the parent side. I was referring the cascade on the child side.

Comment: so call delete()->set parent ref to null in child->set new child to parent->merge parent<

Comment: yes, with one addition: set new child to parent-> **set parent on new child** -> merge parent

Comment: set parent on new child:: save parent should automatically do this. no??

Comment: The `parent` field of the child instance is the source of the foreign key for your persistence provider. According to the JPA (2) spec, the application - in this case, you as it's developer ;) - is responsible for maintaining the relationship data. Please see the edit.

Comment: call delete->set parent ref to null in child trhowiing invalid state exception as child is already deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55833/discussion-between-romi-and-kostja).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the relation in the parent as follows:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "parent")
```

Just set the new child to the parent and merge the parent.  Now the children referencing earlier becomes orphans and JPA automatically deletes those while committing the transaction.

Thanks,
JK

Comment: did you mean , no need to call delete() on child explicetly.

Comment: I am getting the same exception. ConstrainViolation.

Comment: no need to call delete(), instead set the parent to null in deleted child -> set the new child to parent -> merge the parent

Comment: have tried. Its not working. same issue of constrainViolation.

Comment: Did you tried with CascadedType.MERGE instead of CascadeType.ALL.  In my earlier project I faced a similar issue. I removed ALL and added specific cascade types.  Then all went well.  One more thing, as @kostja told, remove the casacadetype in child entity, which may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: caseType.merge in parent or child?? if in parent then a new parent will not persist

Comment: In parent only.  Add what ever you want as a list instead of ALL